# Calling CRT from system spawned thread

Tags: c++, c, winapi, msvcrt, crt

System uses `Create{Remote}Thread` instead of [`_beginthread`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=msvc-170) for callbacks like [ServiceMain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lpservice_main_functiona), [`RegisterServiceCtrlHandlerEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsvc/nc-winsvc-lphandler_function_ex), [HandlerRoutine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) (`SetConsoleCtrlHandler`), etc. Does it mean that it is unsafe to call ***statically*** linked CRT from these threads?

Comment: The support for threadpools added in Win2000 would be more relevant, those threads didn't start through _beginthread either.  That is about as long ago as it has been safe to not rely on _beginthread.  Definitely since VC8 (aka VS2005), possibly VC70 and VC71.

Comment: @HansPassant I specially bolded out `statically linked CRT`. How it would initialize thread locals like `errno` and [gmtime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/gmtime-gmtime32-gmtime64?view=msvc-170) without `DllMain` callback in shared crt dll?

Comment: https://github.com/Chuyu-Team/VC-LTL/blob/a879b308d3d68c7d298db0747203937da235a047/src/ucrt/time/gmtime.cpp#L152

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In modern (UCRT based) runtime `_beginthread{ex}` doesn't do any initialization. It only provide minor services like preventing module from unloading while thread is running and optionally initialize WinRT (`RoInitialize`).